# Can NOT create PlayFramework@2.7.x application

Tags: playframework, sbt

I did `sbt new playframework/play-scala-seed.g8` and some errors occured...

I watched that command at official website.
https://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.7.x/NewApplication

It seems that this error is NOT about PlayFramework and sbt. So I add a tag `sbt`

Anyone help me??

```
[info] Loading project definition from /Users/shinse/go/src/github.com/playframework/playframework.com/project
[debug] Running task... Cancel: Null, check cycles: false, forcegc: true
[info] Updating ProjectRef(uri("file:/Users/shinse/go/src/github.com/playframework/playframework.com/project/"), "playframework-com-build")...
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  ::          UNRESOLVED DEPENDENCIES         ::
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn]  :: com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.dwijnand/sbt-travisci/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.dwijnand/sbt-travisci/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-digest/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-digest/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-gzip/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-gzip/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  :: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-stylus/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-stylus/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  :: com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[warn]  typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.gilt.sbt/sbt-newrelic/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.gilt.sbt/sbt-newrelic/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[warn]  ::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Some unresolved dependencies have extra attributes.  Check that these dependencies exist with the requested attributes.
[warn]      com.gilt.sbt:sbt-newrelic:0.3.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.dwijnand:sbt-travisci:1.1.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-stylus:1.1.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-gzip:1.0.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-digest:1.1.4 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn] 
[warn]  Note: Unresolved dependencies path:
[warn]      com.gilt.sbt:sbt-newrelic:0.3.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/shinse/go/src/github.com/playframework/playframework.com/project/plugins.sbt#L6-7)
[warn]        +- default:playframework-com-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.dwijnand:sbt-travisci:1.1.3 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/shinse/go/src/github.com/playframework/playframework.com/project/plugins.sbt#L1-2)
[warn]        +- default:playframework-com-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-stylus:1.1.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/shinse/go/src/github.com/playframework/playframework.com/project/plugins.sbt#L5-6)
[warn]        +- default:playframework-com-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-gzip:1.0.2 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/shinse/go/src/github.com/playframework/playframework.com/project/plugins.sbt#L4-5)
[warn]        +- default:playframework-com-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.typesafe.sbt:sbt-digest:1.1.4 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/shinse/go/src/github.com/playframework/playframework.com/project/plugins.sbt#L3-4)
[warn]        +- default:playframework-com-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[warn]      com.typesafe.play:sbt-plugin:2.7.0 (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0) (/Users/shinse/go/src/github.com/playframework/playframework.com/project/plugins.sbt#L2-3)
[warn]        +- default:playframework-com-build:0.1.0-SNAPSHOT (scalaVersion=2.12, sbtVersion=1.0)
[debug] Forcing garbage collection...
[error] sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.dwijnand/sbt-travisci/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.dwijnand/sbt-travisci/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-digest/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-digest/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-gzip/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-gzip/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-stylus/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-stylus/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.gilt.sbt/sbt-newrelic/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.gilt.sbt/sbt-newrelic/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.resolveAndRetrieve(IvyActions.scala:332)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.$anonfun$updateEither$1(IvyActions.scala:208)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$$$Lambda$2018/705632270.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.$anonfun$withModule$1(Ivy.scala:239)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module$$Lambda$2019/7285810.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.$anonfun$withIvy$1(Ivy.scala:204)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$Lambda$2020/722709247.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.sbt$internal$librarymanagement$IvySbt$$action$1(Ivy.scala:70)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$$anon$3.call(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withChannel$1(Locks.scala:95)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.xsbt$boot$Locks$GlobalLock$$withChannelRetries$1(Locks.scala:80)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock$$anonfun$withFileLock$1.apply(Locks.scala:99)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.withResource(Using.scala:10)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Using$.apply(Using.scala:9)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.ignoringDeadlockAvoided(Locks.scala:60)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$GlobalLock.withLock(Locks.scala:50)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply0(Locks.scala:31)
[error]     at xsbt.boot.Locks$.apply(Locks.scala:28)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withDefaultLogger(Ivy.scala:77)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:199)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt.withIvy(Ivy.scala:196)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvySbt$Module.withModule(Ivy.scala:238)
[error]     at sbt.internal.librarymanagement.IvyActions$.updateEither(IvyActions.scala:193)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.ivy.IvyDependencyResolution.update(IvyDependencyResolution.scala:20)
[error]     at sbt.librarymanagement.DependencyResolution.update(DependencyResolution.scala:56)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.resolve$1(LibraryManagement.scala:45)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$12(LibraryManagement.scala:93)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$$$Lambda$2014/571722656.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$lastOutput$1(Tracked.scala:68)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$$$Lambda$1971/137510704.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$19(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$$$Lambda$2016/1028413350.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at scala.util.control.Exception$Catch.apply(Exception.scala:224)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11(LibraryManagement.scala:106)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.$anonfun$cachedUpdate$11$adapted(LibraryManagement.scala:89)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$$$Lambda$2013/1092918416.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$.$anonfun$inputChanged$1(Tracked.scala:149)
[error]     at sbt.util.Tracked$$$Lambda$1924/730415936.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.internal.LibraryManagement$.cachedUpdate(LibraryManagement.scala:120)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$.$anonfun$updateTask$5(Defaults.scala:2561)
[error]     at sbt.Classpaths$$$Lambda$1120/513241240.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at scala.Function1.$anonfun$compose$1(Function1.scala:44)
[error]     at scala.Function1$$Lambda$1009/785340693.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater.$anonfun$$u2219$1(TypeFunctions.scala:40)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.$tilde$greater$$Lambda$1836/1539718688.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.std.Transform$$anon$4.work(System.scala:67)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$2(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.Execute$$Lambda$1852/2122147995.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.internal.util.ErrorHandling$.wideConvert(ErrorHandling.scala:16)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.work(Execute.scala:278)
[error]     at sbt.Execute.$anonfun$submit$1(Execute.scala:269)
[error]     at sbt.Execute$$Lambda$1844/270333767.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4.$anonfun$submitValid$1(ConcurrentRestrictions.scala:178)
[error]     at sbt.ConcurrentRestrictions$$anon$4$$Lambda$1851/144486215.apply(Unknown Source)
[error]     at sbt.CompletionService$$anon$2.call(CompletionService.scala:37)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:511)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
[error]     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
[error]     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
[error] (update) sbt.librarymanagement.ResolveException: unresolved dependency: com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.dwijnand/sbt-travisci/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.dwijnand#sbt-travisci;1.1.3: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.dwijnand/sbt-travisci/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.play#sbt-plugin;2.7.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.play/sbt-plugin/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/2.7.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-digest/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-digest;1.1.4: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-digest/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.4/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-gzip/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-gzip;1.0.2: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-gzip/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.0.2/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-stylus/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.typesafe.sbt#sbt-stylus;1.1.0: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.typesafe.sbt/sbt-stylus/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/1.1.0/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error] 
[error] unresolved dependency: com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: Resolution failed several times for dependency: com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3 {compile=[default(compile)]}:: 
[error]     typesafe-ivy-releases: unable to get resource for com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: res=https://repo.typesafe.com/typesafe/ivy-releases/com.gilt.sbt/sbt-newrelic/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[error]     sbt-plugin-releases: unable to get resource for com.gilt.sbt#sbt-newrelic;0.3.3: res=https://repo.scala-sbt.org/scalasbt/sbt-plugin-releases/com.gilt.sbt/sbt-newrelic/scala_2.12/sbt_1.0/0.3.3/ivys/ivy.xml: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: sun.security.validator.ValidatorException: PKIX path building failed: sun.security.provider.certpath.SunCertPathBuilderException: unable to find valid certification path to requested target
[debug] > Exec(loadFailed, None, None)
[debug] > Exec(last, None, None)
```

Comment: I resolved this issue. The problem is missing of cert of typesafe.com.
https://github.com/escline/InstallCert

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some more details to add the cert of typesafe.com to JRE cacerts:

- Download InstallCert from: https://github.com/escline/InstallCert
- javac InstallCert.java
- java InstallCert typesafe.com
- keytool -exportcert -alias typesafe.com-1 -keystore jssecacerts -storepass changeit -file typesafe.com.cer
- keytool -importcert -alias typesafe.com -keystore YOUR_JRE_DIRECTORY\lib\security\cacerts -storepass changeit -file
  typesafe.com.cer

You should change YOUR_JRE_DIRECTORY to a real value. And answer this question with yes:

Trust this certificate? [no]:  yes